# Trying to send telnet commands to a server

Tags: ios, objective-c, telnet

I'm trying to connect to a telnet server (running NetLinx by AMX, in case it matters) and send it a few commands as if I opened Terminal and did "telnet (address)" and started typing commands. I can receive messages but can't send them using this code I found from a tutorial at http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server:

```
- (void)sendMessage: (NSString*) message{ //called when the user interacts with UISwitches, is supposed to send message to server
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]]; //is ASCIIStringEncoding what I want?
[outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
NSLog(@"Sent message to server: %@", message);
}

- (void)initNetworkCommunication { //called in viewDidLoad of the view controller
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"192.168.1.90", 23, &readStream, &writeStream); //192.168.1.90 is the server address, 23 is standard telnet port
    inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];

    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
}
```

It appears to send some kind of message to the server *but maybe in the wrong format*. My guess is that it's a string formatting problem. Is ASCII what I want to use for telnet? If I take the message it prints when it sends a command and paste that right into Terminal with telnet running, the server receives and processes the command normally.

Here is an example command that I'm trying to send: SEND_STRING dvJAND,"'#AUX2=0',$0D"

Another mystery is that, reading the input stream and printing, I see this when the above is sent:

```
2013-08-20 00:20:23.791 [7548:907] server said: S
2013-08-20 00:20:23.793 [7548:907] server said: END_STRING dvJAND,"'#AUX
2013-08-20 00:20:23.795 [7548:907] server said: 2=0',$0D"
```

But when I type that command in Terminal, the server does not respond at all and does its job as it should.

Comment: The telnet protocol is defined in http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that the only thing I was doing wrong was not ending my messages with \r! I read that you need to end with \n, but \r is what did it for me.